# NIFI:Json Content Parsing in FlowFile

Tags: json, groovy, apache-nifi

I have text attribute in GenerateFlowfile processor like this:

```
[{
  "status": {
    "runStatus": "STOPPED"
  },
  "component": {
    "state": "STOPPED",
    "id": "ea5db028-015d-1000-5ad5-80fd006dda92"
  },

  "revision": {
    "version": 46,
    "clientId": "ef592126-015d-1000-bf4f-93c7cf7eedc0"
  }
} ]
```

and related  groovy script in my ExecuteScript processor :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*
def flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile == null) {
    return;
}

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def attrs = [:] as Map<String,String>

session.read(flowFile,
    { inputStream ->
        def text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        text=flowFile.getAttribute('text')
        def obj = slurper.parseText(text)

        obj.each {k,v ->
           attrs[k] = v.toString()
        }
    } as InputStreamCallback)
flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attrs)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

but my processor still shows  me exception like this, what  should i change?
[image]

Comment: Put the  error message rather than  a picture.

Comment: 17:35:04 GET ERROR
ExecuteScript[id=f045f5f8015d-1000-5b1d-9814ac8173f] Fialed to process
session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
javax.lang.MissingMethodException:javax.script.ScriptException:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:No signautre of method:
Script79$_run_closure2.docall is applicable for argument types:
(groovy.json.internal.LazyMap)values:[[component:[id:ea5b028-015d-1000-5a5d5-80fd006dda092,state:STOPPED],..]]

Answer (score 2):

the problem that the root element of your json is an array

and you try to iterate it like map `.each{k,v-> ... }`

probably you want to take the first map to iterate it like in code below

```
def obj=[ [a:1] ]

//this line will throw exception:
//obj.each{k,v-> println "$k->$v" }

//but this one not
obj[0].each{k,v-> println "$k->$v" }
```

fyi: there is a [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) processor that could extract attributes from json flowfile content and put result into attribute

Comment: I  have  tried  it and  even put  this argument in my  flowfile:  component
{id=ea5db028-015d-1000-5ad5-80fd006dda92, state=STOPPING}
id
ea5db028-015d-1000-5ad5-80fd006dda92
path
./
revision
{clientId=f3bada9f-015d-1000-6c6b-d5da64abe343, version=46}
status
{runStatus=STOPPING}
text
{ "revision": { "version": 46, "clientId": "f3bada9f-015d-1000-6c6b-d5da64abe343" }, "status": { "runStatus": "STOPPING" }, "component": { "id": "ea5db028-015d-1000-5ad5-80fd006dda92", "state": "STOPPING" }, "id": "ea5db028-015d-1000-5ad5-80fd006dda92" }
uuid
36ecf731-36b2-4b86-b31e-8f70818aa6c4

Comment: ;  but  invokhttp  still shows  me exception like this :"Invalid attribute <Empty String>"  even  if i use EvaluateJsonPath

Comment: should i make string from json object?

Comment: I guess   the reason why it throws the error  is that i don't write anything in flowfile.

Comment: @daggett is right, this error is caused by referencing the array elements as maps, when really each element is itself a map. If you change obj.each to obj[0].each, it works